# Mesclando colunas no grid system do CSS

Tags: css, grid

Estou fazendo um estudo no grid do CSS e me deparei com um problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei um grid com seis colunas e estou utilizando helpers para determinar quantas colunas vou mesclar. Estou confuso com o fato de que a coluna de 3 unidades da terceira linha é diferente da coluna de 3 unidades da quarta linha. A razão pela qual elas são diferentes tenho uma ideia, mas gostaria de saber se é possível arrumar ou se tem alguma gambiarra para fazer com que essas duas colunas se igualem em largura.

Abaixo está o código CSS.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    --max-width: 1200px;
    --gutter-horizontal: 10px;
    --gutter-vertical: 10px;
    --direction: row;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: var(--max-width);

    row-gap: var(--gutter-vertical);
}

.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);

    column-gap: var(--gutter-horizontal);
    row-gap: var(--gutter-vertical);
}

.col {
    background-color: orangered;
}

.col-1 { grid-column-end: span 1; }
.col-2 { grid-column-end: span 2; }
.col-3 { grid-column-end: span 3; }
.col-4 { grid-column-end: span 4; }
.col-5 { grid-column-end: span 5; }
.col-6 { grid-column-end: span 6; }
```

E aqui o HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grid Layout</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid-layout.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Grid Layout</h1>

    <div class="grid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-1">1 unit</div>
            <div class="col col-1">1 unit</div>
            <div class="col col-1">1 unit</div>
            <div class="col col-1">1 unit</div>
            <div class="col col-1">1 unit</div>
            <div class="col col-1">1 unit</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-2">2 units</div>
            <div class="col col-2">2 units</div>
            <div class="col col-2">2 units</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-3">3 units</div>
            <div class="col col-3">3 units</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-1">1 unit</div>
            <div class="col col-2">2 units</div>
            <div class="col col-3">3 units</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-1">1 unit</div>
            <div class="col col-5">5 units</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-2">2 units</div>
            <div class="col col-4">4 units</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-6">6 units</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso utilizando a unidade de medida `fr`.

> A unidade `fr` representa uma fração do espaço disponível no container
> do grid. [Ir para documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#a_unidade_fr)

```
.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    column-gap: var(--gutter-horizontal);
}
```

Comment: Nossa, tão simples assim!? Ainda acabou esclarecendo a dúvida sobre essa unidade de medida. Não tinha entendido o por que de usar o fr. Obrigado!

Comment: Ao aplicar a unidade `auto` no tamanho da coluna está sendo considerado o tamanho do elemento filho pertencente a coluna. Só não sei dizer o motivo de que o `span` aplicado na propriedade `grid-column-end` estava tendo um tamanho diferente em determinado momento.

Comment: Na verdade não tenho uma resposta concreta. Mas acredito que o motivo da diferença nos tamanhos seja o seguinte: todas as colunas estão com tamanho proporcional as colunas pertencentes a mesma linha. Até aí ok, mas por que o a coluna de 3 unidades da terceira linha (proporção de 1/2) é diferente da 3 unidades da quarta coluna (também de 1/2)? No cálculo não está sendo levado em conta o espaço entre as colunas. Na terceira linha tem menos espaços entre as colunas, logo mais espaço disponível pras elas ocuparem. Já na quarta linha a um espaço a mais, limitando um pouco o espaço disponível.

Comment: Top! Era isso que eu estava tentando entender :) Boa @GabrielMorikawa